how to String.replace() string from lowercase to uppercase with pure regular expression?
I want to replace some character in a string to uppercase with javascript like below.
source: "abcdefgh"
expect: "ab-CD-ef-gh"
my method is:
let str = 'abcdefgh';
let result = str.replace(/ab(.\*)ef(.\*)/g, (...args) =\> \`ab-${args\[1\].toUpperCase()}-ef-${args\[2\]}\`);
console.log(result);

but I try to find a pure regular expression way to do it.
the code is like this:
let str = 'abcdefgh';
let result = str.replace(/ab(.\*)ef(.\*)/g, 'ab-\\L$1-ef-$2'));
console.log(result);

the result is
ab-Lcd-ef-gh
seems not work.
please help, thanks

JavaScript's regex engine does not natively support upper or lower casing the replacement.  In JS your first attempt of using a function in the replacement is the correct approach.


let str = 'abcdefgh';
let result = str.replace(/(..)(..)(.*)/,
    (m, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + "-" + g2.toUpperCase() + g3.replace(/(..)/g, "-$1"));
console.log(result);




seem my origin method is the solution, thanks.
